# Check if a map is initialised in Golang

Tags: json, dictionary, go

I'm decoding some JSON into a struct, and I'd like to handle the case where a particular field is not provided.

Struct:

```
type Config struct {
    SolrHost string
    SolrPort int
    SolrCore string
    Servers  map[string][]int
}
```

JSON to decode:

```
{
  "solrHost": "localhost",
  "solrPort": 8380,
  "solrCore": "testcore",
}
```

In the method that decodes the JSON, I'd like to check if the `map[string][]int` has been initialised, and if not, do so.

Current code:

```
func decodeJson(input string, output *Config) error {
    if len(input) == 0 {
        return fmt.Errorf("empty string")
    }
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(input))
    err := decoder.Decode(output)
    if err != nil {
        if err != io.EOF {
            return err
        }
    }

    // if output.Server.isNotInitialized...

    return nil
}
```

Could I make use of `recover()`? Is that the "nicest" way to achieve my task?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [zero value](http://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) of any map is `nil`, so just check against it:

```
if output.Servers == nil { /* ... */ }
```

Alternatively, you can also check its length. This also handles the case of empty map:

```
if len(output.Servers) == 0 { /* ... */ }
```